# Is there a way to combine 9,12 or 15 columns from a single df into just 3?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to convert a df that has the data divided every 3 columns into just three.
An example is from this:

```
C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6  C7  C8  C9 
1  6   9  A  D  G  1A  6A  9A
2  7  10  B  E  H  2A  7A  10A
3  8  11  C  F  I  3A  8A  11A
```

To this:

```
C1 C2 C3
1  6   9
2  7  10
3  8  11
C4 C5 C6
A  D  G
B  E  H
C  F  I
C7 C8 C9
1A 6A 9A
2A 7A 10A
3A 8A 11A
```

Comment: Are those 3 different DataFrames at the end there? Or just 1?

Comment: It might help to explain a bit why you'd want to do so. This seems like something you would rarely want to do.

Comment: @Metropolis: this is called [***pivoting***](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) (in this case, from wide-form to long-form). Except we generally don't want to pivot the column names `C1 C1 C1`, `C2 C2 C2`, `C3  C3  C3` into actual rows of strings, mixed in with the data; we put them in a separate new column called e.g. `variable`.

Comment: Note that your example is not legal pandas, it's not allowed to have three columns called `C1`, names must be distinct. When we read this in with `pd.read_csv(StringIO(dat), sep='\s+')`, the column names get changed to `C1  C1.1  C1.2 C2 C2.1 C2.2  C3 C3.1 C3.2`. First you need to fix your example.

Comment: This is a duplicate. See the existing thousands of pandas Q&A on `melt`, `pivot`.

Comment: @smci I agree that is a strange transformation but you can't use pivoting here.

Comment: @MykolaZotko: melt, unstack and pivot, in some order. But first the OP must make this illegal example legal. Seems like the header and data rows could only ever have been read in as huge long string, not 3x3 individual columns. This question is [not a reusable resource](https://stackoverflow.com/help) on SO, as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy`:

```
arr = np.hsplit(np.vstack([df.columns.values, df.values]), 3)
pd.DataFrame(np.vstack(arr))
```

Output:

```
     0   1    2
0   C1  C2   C3
1    1   6    9
2    2   7   10
3    3   8   11
4   C4  C5   C6
5    A   D    G
6    B   E    H
7    C   F    I
8   C7  C8   C9
9   1A  6A   9A
10  2A  7A  10A
11  3A  8A  11A
```